# What is the best way to take care of noise in ffmpeg?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I have an old piece of footage that while being high quality is a bit worn and has a lot of film grain and those lines that show up on old film.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a sample video? Or a screenshot if not?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_uNlAHC2KM&pbjreload=101 its the first 10 minutes of this